# Changing class text of only one class in Jquery

Tags: jquery

Alright so I am trying to change only text of the current class not all of them.

For example

```
$(".post_like").click(function() {
    $(".upvotes_changer_inner").text("Hello world");
 });
```

And the HTML would be

```
<div class="post_like">
    <p class="upvotes_changer_inner">
      Change me
    </p>
</div>

<div class="post_like">
    <p class="upvotes_changer_inner">
      Change me
    </p>
</div>

<div class="post_like">
    <p class="upvotes_changer_inner">
      Change me
    </p>
</div>
```

Example on Jsfiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/09jgeb60/

The problem is basically, it should change only the element I've clicked on, not all of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `$(this)` to refer to the element being clicked:

```
$(".post_like").click(function() {
    $(this).find(".upvotes_changer_inner").text("Hello world");
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/05bn14au/)**

Comment: Aha, what about getting the current value of it? I've tried with $(this).find(".upvotes_changer_inner").val(); but I've got a return of undefined

Comment: @TomislavTomiNikolic use:-  `$(this).find(".upvotes_changer_inner").text();`

Comment: For some reason it wont work, could it have something to do with the fact I am generating the content thru PHP MYSQL?

Comment: Nevermind, the problem was with the Jquery itself. I placed the code inside AJAX. This works like a charm! Thanks!